# Proof for generator of vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing

**Given**

$A \in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$ is a static matrix

$W = \{w \in M_{m1}(\mathbb{F})\ | $there is one $x \in M_{n1}(\mathbb{F})$ such that $Ax = w\}$ is a subspace of $M_{m1}(\mathbb{F})$. Proof that the column vectors in $A$ are a generator for $W$.

**Attempt**

$w = Ax = \begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n A_{1i} x_i \\\ ... \\\ \sum_{i=1}^n A_{mi} x_i\end{pmatrix}_{m1}$

We can see that each element $x_i$ in vector $x$ is a coefficient for the i-th column vector in $A$. The linear combination of these column vectors makes up any vector $w \in W$. ◻

Is my approach correct and if so, is this enough for a proof?
I hope that I get a better sense for math during the next days.

Comment: What if we write $Ax$ as $\begin{pmatrix}\!\!\sum_{i_1=1}^n A_{1i_1} x_{i_1} \\ \vdots \\ \!\!\sum_{i_m=1}^n A_{mi_m} x_{i_m} \end{pmatrix}$? How do you write now the vague sentence "each element $x_i$ in vector $x$ is a coefficient for the $i$-th column vector in $A$"?

Comment: @azif00 Thanks for your reply! :) What do you think about continuing like this. $\begin{pmatrix}\!\!\sum_{i_1=1}^n A_{1i_1} x_{i_1} \\ \vdots \\ \!\!\sum_{i_m=1}^n A_{mi_m} x_{i_m} \end{pmatrix}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iA^T_i$

Comment: I realize that this will result in a row vector. The reason for transpose was that I don't know how to address the i-ith column. So maybe transpose the sum again? :D $\begin{pmatrix}\!\!\sum_{i_1=1}^n A_{1i_1} x_{i_1} \\ \vdots \\ \!\!\sum_{i_m=1}^n A_{mi_m} x_{i_m} \end{pmatrix}=(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iA^T_i)^T$

Comment: One question: $A_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of $A$ (which lives in $M_{m1}(\mathbb F)$)?

Comment: @azif00 In my mind, $A_i$ is the i-th row in $A \in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$, and $A^T_i$ is the i-th column (as a row vector since $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$). Is there a better notation? For example, I remember in Octave (Matlab alternative) you can use a colon to indicate that you'd like to get every row. The i-th column would be retrieved using A(:,i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the last comment:

There is no standard notation for the columns, and you can use whichever you like as long as you say what it means. Let's say that the symbol $A_{:,j}$ denotes the $j$-th column of $A$ $($so $A_{:,j} \in M_{m1}(\mathbb F))$. Now, your solution is correct, if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are the coordinates of $x$, then $Ax = \sum_{j=1}^n x_jA_{:,j}$ $($for example $$\begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\ A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_n \end{pmatrix} = x_1 \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} \\ A_{21} \\ A_{31} \end{pmatrix} + x_2 \begin{pmatrix} A_{12} \\ A_{22} \\ A_{32} \end{pmatrix} + x_3 \begin{pmatrix} A_{13} \\ A_{23} \\ A_{33} \end{pmatrix}).$$

Comment: Correct solution means "valid proof"?

Comment: @alberteinstein Yeah, that's what I meant